# Why does Stack Overflow not redirect to HTTPS if I am logged in?

Tags: support, feature-request, login, security, ssl

I often open Stack Overflow from result of search engine. Unfortunately the search engine, let name it G**g**, set the link to `http` instead of `https`. I expect Stack Overflow to redirect to HTTPS because I am logged in. I don't want anyone to steal my access token (such an MITM attack) because HTTP is not secure.

Why does Stack Overflow not redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: Because Stack Exchange doesn't officially support SSL, because the meta subdomains issue (they will need 150+ certificates for all meta.*.se domains)

Comment: Duplicate? I thought the question was different, I was asking about redirection instead of not having. But okay, the answer seems the same.